# nginx: 502 bad gateway if /index.html is not in URL

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-502

i don't understand what i'm doing wrong so i hope somebody can help :)

When i access `http://10.0.0.54/index.html` i get the right page but if i try to access `http://10.0.0.54` instead of showing the index file it redirects me to `https://10.0.0.54` showing error 502 bad gateway.

This is the configuration `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html/salvaderi;

        index index.html;

        server_name _;

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
                allow all;
                root /var/www/html/salvaderi;
        }

        location / {
                root /var/www/html/salvaderi;
                index index.html;
        }
}
```

I am running nginx 1.18.0 on ubuntu 22.04

i tried changing parameters inside `location /{}` but i always get the same result. I also changed the root directory and made sure permission where set right. Searching on for the solution i saw other people having problems about PHP and FastCGI but i am not using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration about to be right.

Possible there is some kind of proxy or load-balancer is placed between you and nginx you configuring since you got redirect to HTTPS whether there is no any redirection instructions in your config and, in the same time, there is no `listen 443 ssl` in config, but you still got response on HTTPS request.

I'd check next:

- Is 10.0.0.54 in fact IP of your server?
- Is there any `return 301`, `return 302` or `rewrite` instructions in your nginx config (the better
  way is to dump config with `nginx -T` command and look over).
- Didn't
  you previously have configured some redirects that may have been
  cached by your web client previously? Try to send GET request with
  curl instead of web browser (if browser been used for tests).

Comment: `Didn't you previously have configured some redirects that may have been cached by your web client previously?` it was this problem. Such a stupid thing to think now, i spent so much time on it... Thank you very much

Comment: I had `location ~ ^/[A-Z]+[a-z0-9]*([A-Z]*[a-z]*)* { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4321; }` in my config from an old wiki, that was causing this.